# Whenever I input data, Moment js gets the wrong UTC

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I've been writing an application for months without having major issues with MomentJs. However, suddenly the library started picking the wrong UTC whenever I input information about the time on moment(). For example:

```
const now = moment();
const then = moment("2021-03-28 08:20 pm", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a");
console.log(now, then)
    
//Output
//Moment<2021-03-26T20:28:15+01:00> Moment<2021-03-28T20:20:00+02:00>
```

I went back and forth on the other topics related here but couldn't find the answer. Other people faced the same problem but for different reasons. How MomentJs can use two UTC if both moments are generated on the same system, hence using the same local timezone? I thought it could be something related to the input `"2021-03-28 08:20 pm"`, but I'm not passing any information regarding the UTC. Has anyone ever faced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't call `console.log` on a `Moment` object directly.  Instead, log the output of the `.format()` function.
- There's no such thing as "the wrong UTC".  There's only one interpretation of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that's why it's Universal.  (It has an offset +00:00).
- Assuming you meant that the two values have different *offsets* from UTC, that is expected when a time zone has transition, either for daylight saving time or for changes in standard time.
- From the dates and offsets you gave (and the location in your Stack Overflow user profile), I will assume that you are working with time in Germany.

  - The time zone ID is `"Europe/Berlin"`.
  - The standard time is known (in English) as Central European Time (CET), which is UTC+1
  - The daylight time is known (in English) as Central European Summer Time (CEST), which is UTC+2
  - In 2021, CEST goes into effect on 2021-03-28 at 02:00 local time, thus explaining the difference in offsets you asked about

You might also want to read the [dst](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) and [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) tag wikis.

Comment: Perfect! I was not considering daylight saving time. And by the wrong UTC, I meant the wrong timezone. But Again it was my lack of attention to the daylight saving time fact. Thanks!